# If a string matches in field A, duplicate row and add second string to row B

Tags: r, split, duplicates, rows

I have a dataframe with text (localities) in the field "residual". I want to search that field, and if a word from a set of key words is found, the row is duplicated, and a corresponding word attached to the key word is added to the field "country"

eg if the word "Alabama" is found in residual, that row is duplicated, and the word "USA" is added to country field from the "codes" associated with Alabama in the keys set.

Strsplit splits along columns, not rows, and separate_rows needs a common delimiter, so I am rapidly out of my depth...

Dummy data:

```
keys <- data.frame(key=c("Canada", "Alabama", "Maryland"), codes=c("CAN", "USA", "USA"))


df <- data.frame(residual=c("Canada, Alabama, Maryland line","Austria","Denver and Boulder","Alabama"),
             country=c("America","Austria","America","America"),
             otherfields=c("foo","foo","foo","foo"))
```

Desired output:

```
result <- data.frame(residual=c("Canada, Alabama, Maryland line",
                            "Canada, Alabama, Maryland line",
                            "Canada, Alabama, Maryland line",
                            "Canada, Alabama, Maryland line",
                            "Austria",
                            "Denver and Boulder",
                            "Alabama",
                            "Alabama"
                            ),
                 country=c("America",
                           "CAN",
                           "USA",
                           "USA",
                           "Austria",
                           "America",
                           "America",
                           "USA"),
                 otherfields=c("foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse option could look as follows.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(country = str_extract_all(residual, str_c(keys$key, collapse = '|')),
         country = map(country, ~ str_replace_all(., deframe(keys)))) %>%
  unnest(country, keep_empty = TRUE)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#   residual                       country otherfields
#   <chr>                          <chr>   <chr>      
# 1 Canada, Alabama, Maryland line CAN     foo        
# 2 Canada, Alabama, Maryland line USA     foo        
# 3 Canada, Alabama, Maryland line USA     foo        
# 4 Austria                        NA      foo        
# 5 Denver and Boulder             NA      foo        
# 6 Alabama                        USA     foo
```

Comment: It's splitting up "Denver and Boulder" - which I understand would be hard  for it to recognize as a single string... Is there a way such that we could return NA to the country field rather than residual if a match is not made from "keys"? That's probably more what I wanted anyway in hindsight

Comment: @BortEdwards: My apologies for the blunder. I have updated my post to correct the error and list ```NA``` where there are no matches with ```keys```.

Comment: @BortEdwards: Please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer, if it solves your problem.